# MSCRM Addcustom filter

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am using MS CRM 2013 and created a custom filter on `ownerid`. It works ok but just that it returns both team and user. I just want to have user. If I provide the entityname as below:

```
 Xrm.Page.getControl("ownerid")
.addCustomFilter(thisfetch, "systemuser");
```

Then it filters on user and returns filtered users and all teams.
How can I fix it?

`thisfetch` is my filter criteria.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructing the Lookup dialog to only allow SystemUser is currently not supported.

There are [unsupported workarounds](http://dynamicscrmusualsuspect.blogspot.de/2014/01/CRM2013ChangedefaultentityforaLookupfield.html) but as pointed out in the linked article they can easily break due to changes in the DOM.

**plain js**

```
function setToFieldFilter()
{
    document.getElementById("to_i").setAttribute("lookuptypenames", "systemuser:8:User");
    document.getElementById("to_i").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "8");
}

function onLoad()
{
    Xrm.Page.getControl("ownerid").addPreSearch(setToFieldFilter);
}
```

**jquery**

```
$("#to_i").attr("lookuptypenames", "systemuser:8:User");
$("#to_i").attr("lookuptypes", "8");
```

---

*Sources*

[CRM 2013 : Change default entity for a Lookup field](http://dynamicscrmusualsuspect.blogspot.de/2014/01/CRM2013ChangedefaultentityforaLookupfield.html)

[Filter PartyList entities Lookup using Jscript in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://lakshmanindian.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/filter-partylist-entities-lookup-using-jscript-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/)